# Android appcompt library 23.1.1: TabLayout.Tab.setCustomView() NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Since upgrading from 23.1.0 to 23.1.1 of the appcompat library, calling `setCustomView()` on a `TabLayout.Tab` throws a `NullPointerException`.

eg

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.newTab();
tab.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_photo_indicator);
mTabLayout.addTab(tab);
```

Throws a `NullPointerException` on the second line. The exception points to `TabLayout.java:1019` inside the appcompat library, the `inflater =` line below:

```
public Tab setCustomView(int resId) {
    final TabView tabView = mParent.getTabView(mPosition);
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(tabView.getContext());
    return setCustomView(inflater.inflate(resId, tabView, false);
}
```

Downgrading back to 23.1.0 makes it work again, but 23.1.1 fixes a different issue I experience in that version.

Is there something wrong in what I'm doing or is this an issue in the support library?

Comment: This has been rasied as a bug with google, confirmed and should be fixed in a future release: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=194652

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the tab to the layout before setting the custom view avoids the crash. eg:

```
TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.newTab();
mTabLayout.addTab(tab);
tab.setCustomView(R.layout.tab_photo_indicator);
```

Unfortunately the layout doesn't display exactly as before but I was able to modify the layout to suit.

This issue also precludes creating and adding the tab as a one liner. eg:

```
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(r.layout.tab_photo_indicator));
```

Comment: Did you the solution for "Unfortunately the layout doesn't display exactly as before but I was able to modify the layout to suit."

Comment: No I didn't document how I had to modify the layout.

The original bug is corrected in 23.2.1 so this now works as expected:
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(r.layout.tab_photo_indicator));

Answer (score -1):

Plz update com.android.support:appcompat-v7 to 23.1.1.

It's because that 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1 and com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 adjust package structure.You should use the same version.